# How to count values, and then return a number as a value changes

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007

I have a list of grades, which are worked out against grade boundaries in a table. I would like to give the student extra information on how many marks they would need to get the grade above the one that they are currently at.

The data looks like this:

Pupil          Mark   Grade 
A, Student     51       7

I have a table in a second sheet that looks like this:

Mark      Grade 
49          7 
50          7 
51          7 
52          7 
53          7 
54          8 
55          8

What I would like is to look at the mark in sheet one, count how many cells between the current mark and the next grade, and return the value. In this case, the student needs to gain 3 more marks to get to a grade 8, so I would like it to return 3.

Is this possible? Many thanks! Apologies for my formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way. First, switch the Mark and Grade columns in your reference table. Make the grade as your first column. Then, make sure it's sorted from lowest to highest by Mark.

Then, here's the formula for cell D2:

```
    =VLOOKUP(C2+1,G:H,2,FALSE)-B2
```

Adjust the look-up array as needed (G:H in my case).

Drag it down and you're done. This works as long as your data are correctly sorted in the reference table. It's looking for the **first** match. You may want to add an error handler in case someone already has a top grade.

[image]